# Using a string as an expression to be send to eval() and replacing a sub-string with a vriable value PHP

Tags: php, expression, eval, quotes, str-replace

I need some help with basic syntax in PHP,

I got the following string :
`$str = "return (strlen(replace) <= 5 && strlen(replace) >= 1);";`

and I got a variable : `$var = "VariableValue";`

and the st_replace function as : `str_replace('replace', $var, $str);`

What I am trying to do is actually use eval in somehing like:

```
if(eval($str)){//This should now make the if condition **look like**               
               //if(strlen(*'VariableValue'*)...) 
               //

echo 'Success';

}else{

     echo 'Ask the guys at StackOverFlow :),sure after searching for it';
}
```

So if you notice what is if(strlen(*'VariableValue'*)...) this is what I want to do,make the final if statement after eval containing the vars value WITH QUOTES so strlen actually process it,

I hope I made clear as needed :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

```
$str = "return (strlen(##replace##) <= 5 && strlen(##replace##) >= 1);";
$var = 'test';

// you have to assign the str_replace to $str again. And use " around the $var.
$str = str_replace('##replace##', '"' . addslashes($var) . '"', $str);

if (eval($str)) {             
    echo 'Success';
}
else {
    echo 'Ask the guys at StackOverFlow :),sure after searching for it';
}
```

I added the ## around replace because it's a good idea to always have a somewhat unique string to replace... like when you expand your eval'd code to include `str_replace`, then that would be replaced too otherwise.

**EDIT**
Escaped the $var with `addslashes` as per @Erbureth's comment.

Comment: You should escape the variable string in case it contains quotes or other control characters

Comment: Terrific,Thanks a lot,Do you think there is other way to do what I am trying to do without using eval (but only with the same technique)

Comment: As @arkascha stated in the other answer: use the variable directly: so instead of `if (eval($code)) {...}` do `if (strlen($var) <= 5 && strlen($var) >= 1) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

aYou don't need eval() for that (there are reason why it is sometimes called evil()...).

Just try a condition like that:

```
if ( (strlen($var) <= 5) && (strlen($var) >= 1) )
```

Comment: True, this is not a good use for eval, but if eval was pure evil and had no use-cases it wouldn't still be around. Or it would at least be deprecated in PHP 5.4

Comment: @SJFrK: I never claimed it is pure evil.

Comment: Sorry if I sounded rude, that was not my intention. I just don't like all those wars about eval good or evil, database table names plural or singular, opening braces on same line or next line etc.

Comment: @SJFrK: I absolutely agree with you. I don't want to start a fight or anything. I just want to mention that eval() _can_ be evil, and that thinking twice if you really really have to use it absolutely makes sense. In 98% of the cases there are simpler and safer solutions.

Comment: Guys Is it enough secure if I am only using eval, i.e. I am replacing a const strings that I only Know ?

Comment: That is absolutely safe, sure. Though: why use eval() when you deal only with constants?

Comment: Unneccessary complex, really hard to debug and it adds a huge performance penalty since AFAIK each eval() requires another interpreter instance to be forked. Asked the other way round: what is the advantage of using such a complex approach if there is a much more simple one?

Comment: Mechanism,That is why,I am try to create a function that receives a set of conditions and validate if an input valid,the whole thing of it is to prevent code duplication and if statements with a flag var to check if each conditions works,but now,after what you have told me I am guessing it is better just to create a class for each object for example for the user and when creating the user verifying if it passes all conditions,What do you think ? thanks a lot.