# unable to get preg_match to work correctly PHP(This relates to another post)

Tags: php, expression, match

I am having a hard time with `preg_match`, this is an earlier question I asked:

[Using a string as an expression to be send to eval() and replacing a sub-string with a vriable value PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744654/using-a-string-as-an-expression-to-be-send-to-eval-and-replacing-a-sub-string)

Now I am trying to give str a preg_match like the following:

```
$str =  "return (!(preg_match('/[^A-Za-z$]+/', ##replace##)));"
```

If I am correct this will return TRUE if I give  ##replace## the value "ValueWithNumber4",

So where is the issue and how am I supposed to change it?

Comment: Why are you using eval for gods sake?

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match` doesn't replace anything, it *matches*.  It returns `true` if the value in `##replace##` matches the expression given (it will since there is a non-Alpha/$ in "ValueWithNumber4." -- and it does, I tested it)  I think that your expression is incorrect, though.  You probably want

```
/^[A-Za-z]+$/
/* or */ /^[a-z]+$/i
```

Comment: $str is going to be thrown to str_replace to replace ##replace## by "ValueWithNumber4" and then used in an eval...